# Global variables, what are they exactly?

Tags: c++, variables, global

First of all, I'm new to c++, and 'trying' to prefix my variables.
But it isn't very clear to me.
So my question is, is it correct to prefix static variables with "g_"?
Thank you!

```
using namespace std;

// The main window class name.
static TCHAR g_szWindowClass[] = _T("win32app");

// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR g_szTitle[] = _T("Win32 App");

...
```

Comment: A global variable is any variable that isn't inside of a class or function.  As for is it correct-  sure, if you want.  It isn't illegal.  Its all a question of style, and there is no correct answer for that.

Comment: I don't prefix variables.

Comment: I am afraid there is no such thing as "correct" as far as naming conventions go. IMHO, the one you're proposing is not unreasonable. That said, I am sure some people will disagree. In any event, the most important thing is that you're *consistent* in following whatever convention you choose.

Comment: In the Windows world (and this looks like winapi code), Hungarian notation, `m_` and `g_` and so on are pretty standard.  I don't see them much elsewhere though, and I've never used that style myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious definition of a *global variable* is a variable declared at namespace scope (including the outermost namespace).

Now, you could argue that a variable declared at namespace scope which is also declared `static` and, thus, isn't visible outside the given translation unit. Likewise, a variable declared in an unnamed namespace might be considered non-global. However, both of these kinds of variables shared many of the the bad properties of global variables. For example, they introduce a serialization point when being accessed from multiple threads.

Thus, I consider actually a wider range of variables to be global, i.e., also `static` data members in classes and function locale `static` variables. Each of these also exists just once throughout a a program. Just because these constructs happen to be used for some [anti] design patterns (notable Singleton) doesn't magically bless global variables!

With respect to prefixing variables names: do *not* include type prefix into your variable names! In C++ types are already sufficiently checked by the compiler. Including the type tends to result in eventually incorrect names. Specifically with respect to global variables, here is my recommendation for their prefix: whenever you want to use the prefix for a global variable stop whatever you are doing! You are in the process of constructing a problem and you should rather seek to change the design to remove the need for the global variable!

Comment: But the different categories are global and problematic to various degrees. Those variables that are accessible only in one translation unit are less problematic in practice. Are you sure should include all kinds in your post as just "global variables"?

Comment: @user2672165: "global" is the opposite of "local". with a local variable there is just one possible scope, namely the local scope at hand. with a global one there are numerous possible scopes, namely all those that include the local scope. if the word "global" should not refer to them, but only to sort of maximally global variables, then we need a new word for the former general meaning of "global". however, I would rather invent a new word or descriptive term for the most globally global, e.g. "application-global".

Comment: @user2672165: although the more local scopes may not have some of the problems a namespace level variable has, they are mostly equivalent and should be avoided. Essentially, it amounts to global variables stay global variables even when trying to obfuscate their nature.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use a prefix than nothing that distinguishes global variables as such. But

- it's even better to avoid global variables to the degree possible, and
- instead of a C style prefix, in C++ you can use a named **namespace**.

It also has many advantages to avoid Microsoft's `T` macro silliness. It's in support of Windows 9x, and you're probably not targeting Windows 9x. Also, it has many advantages, not the least for maintenance, to avoid Microsoft's silly Hungarian notation thing, that is, prefixes like `sz`, which was in support of Microsoft's 1980's *Programmers Workbench* help system, which just like Windows 98 is not very relevant any longer.

Also, it can be advantageous to use `const` wherever practically possible.

Note that `const` at namespace level implies static storage class, so an explicit `static` is then no longer necessary.

Thus, instead of the current

```
// The main window class name.
static TCHAR g_szWindowClass[] = _T("win32app");
```

do

```
namespace g {
    auto const windowClassName = L"win32app";
}
```

with

- C++ namespace `g` instead of C prefix `g_`,
- `const` added, guaranteeing that this variable is not modified, and
- direct use of wide character literal instead of Microsoft Windows 9x `T` macros.

Then you can refer to `g::windowClassName`, or without the prefix after a `using namespace g;`, or even with an alias for `g`.

The particular braces convention I use for namespaces is in support of nested namespaces without the indentation hassle. Unfortunately that's not supported by common editors.

Comment: Do you need the '[]' when using auto in that way?

Comment: Agree, but in practice for real sources I find it better to have namespaces logically divided instead of just a dedicated global, but of course if you really focus on separating globals from the rest it is good.

Comment: @NeilKirk: the `[]` was wrong (`auto` would not work with it), but my connection is very slow, so editing is and proofreading is a time consuming hassle. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has no official naming conventions. It does have a few **rules** for variable names, or identifers in general, which you have to follow, but other than that, names are entirely up to you, with all the flexibility and dangers it brings (much like the rest of the language).

Here is a good overview of the rules: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

So, for example, `_G_szTitle` would be wrong, but `g_szTitle` is OK.

The real problem is that you almost certainly do not want to use globals. Global variables are almost always **bad design**. Avoid them.

Another, smaller, problem is that you use the so-called "Hungarian notation". Google a bit for it to find out why many people (myself included) are opposed to it, especially in a language like C++.

Comment: Didn't realize that underscore rule. You can create a variable called _G_szTitle, however it's bad practice. Is that correct?

Comment: You can create it, and your compiler may swallow it, but it makes your code illegal C++.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 Standard (draft n3337):

> 17.6.4.3.2 Global names [global.names]
>
> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> — Each name that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
>
> — Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

Other than these there aren't any restrictions on the (identifier) names you choose for global variables.

It's a convention used by some to prefix global variables by `g_`, member variables by `m_`, etc. This is a matter of choice; the language itself doesn't impose such a requirement. So you're free to name them anything and prefix them with anything as long as the identifier starts with an English alphabet.

As for the usage of global variables, I would say if you are just beginning to learn C++, use them, get hurt and then realize how they are bad; you'll see why they are always condemned by experienced programmers. Just telling they're bad would add little value, some things are better learned by experience.

Comment: Not using globals because everyone (teachers, gurus, people on the Internet) tells you they are bad is easy. I avoided them right from the beginning because I was taught to strictly avoid them. However, I only really *understood* why when I realised, many years later, that the Singleton design pattern is little more than a glorified global variable.